# Trying to prevent call of 'OnSelectedIndexChanged' in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with gridview on clicking the row1 and column1 item which is hyperlinked a page webpage is opened with data populated and a submit button.but while clicking on submit button the 'OnSelectedIndexChanged' event. in gridview is called again.HOw can i prevent that event from calling again on click of submit button in that web page.

Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"   AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:GridView>
```

c#

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (IsPostBack==false)
  {
    BindDropdown();
    }      
 }



 protected void gvCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string test = gvCustomers.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            TW12HVGI(test);
            gvCustomers.Visible = false;
            pdfFormInsideL1n.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: "a page webpage is opened with data populated and a submit button..." Where is this page?

Comment: @wazz it's inside  <asp:Panel ID="pdfFormInsideL1n" runat="server" Visible="false"> </asp:panel>

Comment: Sorry the question is not clear. Try rewriting. Be very precise about the problem and show all relevant code and markup. tnx.